# Decrease the variance of ExtraTrees Classifier

Tags: machine-learning, logistic, random-forest, ensemble-learning, stacking

I am trying to solve a machine learning problem. I am using ExtraTrees Classifier. When I am plotting the learning curves, I can see a wide gap. I need to decrease that (variance). I read about stacking classifier from https://blog.statsbot.co/ensemble-learning-d1dcd548e936 .

The issue is when I am trying to combine ExtraTrees Classifier with Random Forest and SVM I am always getting the stacked classifier identical to the ExtraTrees Classifier. I thought that I should be able to decrease its variance as Random Forest and SVM both have learning curves very close to each other.The meta classifier I am using is Logistic Regression.

Example implementation is used from here : https://rasbt.github.io/mlxtend/user_guide/classifier/StackingClassifier/

Kindly help.